# How to close a task created with asyncqt.QEventLoop in PyQt5

Tags: pyqt5, python-asyncio, mitmproxy

I want to use PyQt5 to access flows in mitmproxy. Since mitmproxy is asynchronous, I use asyncqt.QEventLoop to create a loop to share with mitmproxy. I can start the mitmproxy master service now, but I am unable to stop the master service. How can I correctly stop this task?

```
import asyncio
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from asyncqt import QEventLoop
from mitmproxy import addons
from mitmproxy.options import Options
from mitmproxy.master import Master

class MitmProxy:
    def __init__(self, options: Options) -> None:
        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        print(id(loop), loop)
        self.master = Master(options, event_loop=self.loop)
        self.master.addons.add(*addons.default_addons())

    def run(self) -> None:
        self.task = self.loop.create_task(self.master.run())

    def stop(self) -> None:
        self.task.cancel()
        if self.task.cancelled():
            print("task cancelled, shutdown")
            self.master.shutdown()
        print('task cancel over')

class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self.mitm = None

        self.lyt = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.btn_start = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Start")
        self.btn_stop = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Stop")

        self.btn_start.clicked.connect(self.add_task)
        self.btn_stop.clicked.connect(self.stop_task)

        self.lyt.addWidget(self.btn_start)
        self.lyt.addWidget(self.btn_stop)

    def add_task(self):
        self.mitm = MitmProxy(
            Options(listen_host="0.0.0.0", listen_port=8080, http2=True)
        )
        self.mitm.run()

    def stop_task(self):
        self.mitm.stop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    loop = QEventLoop(app)
    print(id(loop), loop)
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

    label = MyWidget()
    label.show()

    with loop:
        loop.run_forever()
```

Comment: Have you tried `master.shutdown()` https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/a26013908a95a270291de4c462d4074477b9a8d2/mitmproxy/tools/console/consoleaddons.py#L333

Comment: Here is the source code where I have already called the shutdown method: 


`self.event_loop.call_soon_threadsafe(self.should_exit.set)`  


When executing on the master, it will await Event, but when I debug, it does not trigger `await self.should_exit.wait() `as expected.

Comment: mitmproxy is developed as stand-alone program, using it as library for integration in other programs is no longer supported so it is possible that there is no function to shut down mitmproxy except from stopping the whole process.

Comment: I can start and stop the master properly by executing it in a new event loop within `threading.Thread`.